# external page fit inside div

Tags: html, css

i made external page(php) display inside `div` Problem is when i display external page inside div

### PROBLEM

external page content moves outside of div **i need external page content to fit inside div**

### CSS

```
.page{float:right;width:88%;background-color:snow}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="page">
// external page loads inside this div
                </div>
```

### output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/APi69.png

Comment: have you tried overflow:hidden?

Comment: @DaveB yes trier content outside div are hidden

Comment: What do you mean by "fit" ? Scale? Wrap long words? From the screenshot it is not clear, what is your div, what is the external page and how do you like it to be shown.

Comment: @mirelon not wrap check image you will see two span on top are outside

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow:hidden to fit the inner content (hiding anything thats bigger than the outer DIV)

If you want to fit everything inside without hiding anything you need to apply CSS to the inner content to make it small to fit inside your DIV

Comment: its external page how can i make that external page contan `<html><body>page content</body></html>`

Comment: you can add CSS to your page that will override the styles from the external page